# In perl match a dot when there're at least three words before it

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using `(?<=(?:(?:\w|,|'){1,20} ){2}(?:\w|,|'){1,20} ?)\.`
But it's not working as expected:

```perl
use v5.35.2;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = shift // q{If you have to go. you go. That's no problem.}; 

my $regex = qr/(?<=(?:(?:\w|,|'){1,20} ){2}(?:\w|,|'){1,20} ?)\./;

my @all_parts = split $regex, $str;

say for@all_parts;
```

It should print out `If you have to go` and  `you go. That's no problem`

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my $str = shift // q{If you have to go. you go. That's no problem.}; 
my $regex = qr/(?:\b[\w,']+\s*){3}\K\./; 
my @all_parts = split $regex, $str;
say for @all_parts;
```

splits like you want. Using `\K` to discard everything before the period from the actual match is the key bit. (There's probably tweaks that could be made to the RE to better account for edge cases you didn't provide in your example string).

Comment: Doesn't work. Splits `a's b. c` even though it shouldn't because the `.` is only preceded by two words.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
split / [\w'] (?: [\s,]+ [\w']+ ){2} \K \. /x
```

Notes:

- It's usually easier and more efficient to use `\K` instead of a lookbehind. It also has the advantage that can look further back than the 255 chars a real variable-length lookbehind can look back. But it has the disadvantage that it can't "look behind" further than the end of the previous match. This isn't a problem here.
- Feel free to remove the whitespace. If you do, you can also remove the `x`.
- Adding a `+` after each existing `+` should make it a tiny bit faster.
- You obviously consider `a's` to be one word, but the earlier answer can count it as two. For example, it considers the `.` to be preceded by three words in `a's b. c`.